# How to set OnClick listener for Tab in TabBar?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

In advance, sorry for my English (I'm from Russian, but on ru.stack I didn't receive an answer for my question)
So, I have an idea: I have 2 `TabBar`s in one `Shell` and I need realize switch `TabBar` by click on `Tab` from first `TabBar`. I think that I need something like OnClickListener, but I don't know how to create or override him.

I tried to use transit-ContentPage:

`Tab`-start from first `TabBar`:

```
<ShellContent
                x:Name="tabMain"
                Title="На главную"
                Icon="Images/ChatsPage/main_page.svg"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate help:toHomeShell}"/>
```

toHomeShell.xaml.cs:

```
public toHomeShell()
    {
        Content = new VerticalStackLayout
        {
            Children = 
            {
                new Image 
                {
                    Source="Images/ChatsPage/background.svg",
                    Aspect=Aspect.AspectFill,
                    ZIndex=0,
                    HeightRequest =10000
                }
            }
        };
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//session");
```

but this working so long and I think, it isn't good code. Please help me :) Thank u so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add PropertyChanged event to your Tabbar. Like this:

```
private void listenerChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listener = sender as TabBar;
    if (listener.CurrentItem.Title=="One")
    {
    }
    else if (listener.CurrentItem.Title == "Two") { }
}
```

For shell.xaml:

```
<TabBar PropertyChanged="listenerChanged">
     <Tab Title="One" Icon="{StaticResource IconOne}">
         <ShellContent
             Title="One"
             ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
             Route="OnePage" />
     </Tab>
     <Tab Title="Two" Icon="{StaticResource IconTwo}">
         <ShellContent
             Title="Two"
             ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
             Route="TwoPage" />
     </Tab>
```

Comment: Is there a way for this to trigger if you click on the tab you are already on? Say I'm on my home tab if I click on the home tab again the PropertyChanged event doesn't fire which makes sense but is there an event that I can tie into anytime a tab is clicked?